# Counting quantity of children with recursion

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have tables such as shown on pictures below. Category has hierarchy tree by parent_id. CategoryProducts makes many-to-many relation between Category and Product. One product can be in different categories. Eg "red ball" can be placed in "sport" and "sport"-s sub-category "football".

How to count the number of products in each category with product amount from a subcategory? Duplication does not matter, for example, category "sport" can contain two "red ball"(one from own category, one from sub-category "football").

table relations:

[image: table relations]

result table:

[image: result table]

Here is sql script that is not working correctly:

```
    with recursive category_tree as (
    select c.id , c.name , c.parent_id , count(cp.id) as amo
    from temp_category_2 c
    join temp_category_products cp on cp.category_id = c.id
    where c.parent_id = null
    group by c.id
    
    union 
    
    select c2.id , c2.name , c2.parent_id , (select count(cp.id) from temp_category_products cp where cp.category_id = c2.id) as amo
    from temp_category_2 c2 
    join category_tree ct on ct.id = c2.parent_id 
)
select cat.id , cat.parent_id, 
count(cp.id) + coalesce((
    select sum(ct.amo)
    from category_tree ct 
    where ct.parent_id = cat.id
    group by ct.parent_id),0)as amount
from temp_category_2 cat
join temp_category_products cp on cp.category_id = cat.id
group by cat.id , cat.parent_id
;
```

TABLE category:

```
  id |   name   | parent_id | product_quantity
----+----------+-----------+------------------
  2 | a        |         1 |                3
  3 | s        |         1 |                3
  4 | d        |         2 |                3
  5 | f        |         2 |                4
  6 | g        |         3 |                2
  1 | main     |           |                0
(6 rows)
```

TABLE product:

```
 id |  name
----+---------
  1 | example
  2 | example
  3 | example
  ...
(15 rows)
```

TABLE category_products:

```
 id | category_id | product_id
----+-------------+------------
  1 |           6 |          1
  2 |           6 |          2
  3 |           5 |          3
  4 |           5 |          4
  5 |           5 |          5
  6 |           5 |          6
  7 |           4 |          7
  8 |           4 |          8
  9 |           4 |          9
 10 |           3 |         10
 11 |           3 |         11
 12 |           3 |         12
 13 |           2 |         13
 14 |           2 |         14
 15 |           2 |         15
(15 rows)
```

Result of my query(incorrect result):

```
 id | parent_id | amount
----+-----------+--------
  3 |         1 |      3
  5 |         2 |      4
  4 |         2 |      3
  6 |         3 |      2
  2 |         1 |      3
(5 rows)
```

Right result should be:

```
id | parent_id | amount
----+-----------+--------
  1 |           |      15
  2 |         1 |      10
  3 |         1 |      5
  4 |         2 |      3
  5 |         2 |      4
  6 |         3 |      2
(6 rows)
```

Comment: I find your Question clear, but it contains images, which is difficult for some users to see. Can you give a small sample data as text, and show what your query is finding from the sample data, and what it's suppose to find instead?

Comment: @Scratte i have edited my post. Can you check it again?

Comment: The SQL is very helpful, thanks :) I think that your tables should be presented as ascii tables. Again the issue is that a lot of users will not be able to see the images. I think it would also make it easier if you were to give the result of the query that doesn't work correctly. Please note that all important information should be provided as text. Images should only be an additional visualization, which is nice for your first two images of the table relations. You can use [this tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) to create ascii tables :)

Answer (score 0):

After some effort I have found an answer. A similar example is shown on [this blog](https://facility9.com/2009/07/counting-children-with-ctes/).

The right sql was:

```
with recursive  cte(CategoryId, ParentCategoryId, c)
        AS (SELECT  c1.id,
                    c1.parent_id ,
                    (SELECT COUNT(*)
                     FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT
                                    product_id 
                             FROM   temp_category_products AS tcp
                             WHERE  tcp.category_id = c1.id
                            ) AS t1
                    ) AS c
            FROM    temp_category AS c1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  c2.id,
                    c2.parent_id ,
                    d.c
            FROM    temp_category c2
                    INNER JOIN cte d ON c2.id = d.ParentCategoryId
           )
  SELECT  cte.CategoryId,
          cte.ParentCategoryId,
          SUM(c) AS ProductCount
  FROM    cte
  GROUP BY cte.CategoryId,
          cte.ParentCategoryId;
```